# PHP fastest way to iterate over list?

Tags: php, list, loops, if-statement, switch-statement

I need to iterate over 15 cases, about 2 mio times per day. This cases are my "blocked ISPs list". If a visitor has this ISP, they will not see my site. When a visitor visits my site, its ISP will be detected and saved under `$ISP`. This is my current solution:

```
<?php
$ISP = "vodafone";

switch ($ISP) {
    case "telecom":
        x=1;
        break;
    case "vodafone":
        x=1;
        break;

...

  default:
        x=0;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: if (isset ($list[$ISP])) x=1;

Comment: Rather than `in_array()`, create the array using the values that you want to check as the array keys, then `isset($ispArray[$ISP])`

Comment: @MarkBaker Why would you prefer `isset` ?

Comment: @Veeza - `in_array()` searches each element in turn until it finds a match, so it's O(n), plus the overhead of a function call.... isset() is a direct lookup on the key, so O(1), and it's a language construct rather than a function call, so eliminates that additional overhead